# Lines do not break for Chinese text in a braces scope

Tags: babel, chinese, etoc

In our team we are encountering an issue with the line break of Chinese text when using the packages babel and etoc and compiling with xelatex. The issue only occurs when the content is placed within a braces scope. Since we are using a loop to import files for a total of 16 languages into a document, we depend on that scope. It works fine for all other languages.

So this actually occurred in a very complex setup in which we absolutely need the braces, but we were able to break it down to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{chinese}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FandolSong-Regular.otf}
\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}

{ % Usage of this brace triggers the problem
\selectlanguage{chinese}
\localtableofcontents

\section{简体中文}

简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。

简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。
} % Usage of this brace triggers the problem

\end{document}
```

Without the braces, the line break is fine. When introducing the braces, the lines run out of the page. (After the first compile run the line break is still fine. You have to compile twice.)

Does Chinese need any additional option here? Is this a bug in babel or etoc?

Note: We know that the problem does not occur when compiling with lualatex. Switching to lualatex however is currently not possible, because we are encountering massive performance issues with that engine - but that is a different topic ;)

Comment: I don't know what exactly is happening, but there are lots of language switches in the aux and in the toc and somehow you loose the linebreak locale setting after the local toc. Try `\localtableofcontents \selectlanguage{chinese}`

Comment: Yes, that works. Thing is however, that in the bigger setup with hundreds of files, I am actually controlling  `\selectlanguage` in the Preamble with a `\IfSubStr` condition on a locale code in the files names. Actually the line break locale setting shouldn't be lost after the local toc, right?

Comment: well language calls do not always honor groups, settings can escape (`\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"` eg.. is an example). babel writes lots of language changes into the toc and the aux, and with your group the last language in the toc is english and so if affects following text.

Comment: And why does it happen with the braces? Because `babel` restores the language when the group ends (in other words, there is an implicit `\selectlanguage{english}`), and this change is written to the `toc` file, which is the last one. And as @UlrikeFischer has pointed out, `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` is set globally (which is, imo, a quite unexpected behavior). Very likely, there is a workaround (not sure), if patching `\localtableofcontents` is an option.

Comment: So, do I understand correctly that in my setup after the `\localtableofcontents`, the language is set back to English? But then, if I add a table with a caption to the text coming afterwards, why is a table caption still saying "表 1" in Chinese? Shouldn't it put "table" in English then?

Comment: The document appears to compile fine under LuaLaTeX. Any chance you could switch from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @suricata78 Because these changes are local, while `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` is global. And the code in `\localetableofcontexts` is executed inside a group. Everything is restored except the line breaking rules.

Comment: @Mico As I mentioned in the post, I know it is compiling fine under LuaLaTeX, but we currently cannot switch due to performance issues with that engine - whole different story... This will be my next question for the community ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments, I’d say `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` isn’t very well behaved wrt scoping. Sometimes seems global, sometimes seems local. Either I’m missing something or there is some bug in `xetex`. Here is the workaround I was thinking of in my comment above, following a suggestion by @UlrikeFischer, which admittedly isn’t very efficient. Just add after loading `etoc`:

```
\addto\localtableofcontents{%
  \expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\languagename}}
```

This will re-select the current language and therefore reset `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale`.

Comment: Thank you for that workaround, it works fine! I'll accept this answer, however, I really think `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` should behave like all the other language changes. As a user of babel there is no way to know why some changes are global and others are local.

Comment: I think so, but `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` (to my surprise) makes global assignments, which is a very bad thing, because once a global setting has been made, there is no way to ‘unglobalize’ it or to catch where this should be done. I’ll try to investigate a solution, but this is a, imo, severe issue in `xetex`. So, ask for help to improve the performance of luatex .

Comment: `\renewcommand{\etocaftertochook}{\expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\languagename}}` is less hacky;  in preamble after loading `etoc` as it does not seem to hurt even if executed by the main toc.

Answer (score 3):

The linebreaking is controlled by the setting of `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale`. That is a global setting, and so ignores groups:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FandolSong-Regular.otf}
\begin{document}

\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh" 
简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体
中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体
中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体
中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体
中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体
中文。简体中文，简体中文。

{\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "" 
 简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中
文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中
文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中
文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中
文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中
文。} 

简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中
文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中
文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中
文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中
文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中
文。

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now when you switch languages babel will write also suitable language switches to the toc (and the aux-file):

```
\babel@toc {english}{}\relax 
\babel@toc {chinese}{}\relax 
\etoc@startlocaltoc {1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}简体中文}{1}{}%
\babel@toc {english}{}\relax
```

If the last language in the toc is english, it will reset `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` globally to empty and so your line breaking no longer works.

In a complex document it is not easy to control which language switch is at the end of the toc, so the best is to reset the language after the toc to the right language.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It helped understanding the problem and I appreciate it. I accepted @Javier Bezos answer though because it actually solved the problem.

Comment: well he does what I wrote: reset the language (personnally I would use `\AddToHook{cmd/localtableofcontents/after}{\ExpandArgs{o}\selectlanguage{\languagename}}`, but at the end it depends on your real code, was makes the most sense)

Comment: That actually does suit our real code better, thank you! My apologies for not seeing the similarity of the answers.

Comment: I have not tested but wouldn't `\AddToHook{cmd/localtableofcontents/after}` break `\localtableofcontents` "look-ahead" for following `\label` or `\ref` tokens? There is a macro `\etocaftertochook` which is freely available for redefinition according to `etoc` doc albeit less fancy than `\AddToHook`.

Comment: I confirm using `\AddToHook{cmd/localtableofcontents/after}{stuff}` breaks `\localtableofcontents` feature of detecting `\label/\ref` for special handling.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to the OP's question, but a suggestion that a fairly straightforward solution may be at hand: Making the switch from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX. For sure, the OP's code compiles just fine under LuaLaTeX, with or without the curly braces.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{chinese}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FandolSong Regular}
\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}

{ % Usage of this brace no longer triggers the problem
\selectlanguage{chinese}
\localtableofcontents

\vspace{7mm}\hrule % <-- new

\section{简体中文}

简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。

简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。简体中文简体中文。简体中文，简体中文。
} % Usage of this brace no longer triggers the problem

\end{document}
```